# Is R-{0} under the operation a*b=|ab| a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the set R-{0} under the operation a*b=|ab|, is the set a group?

What I've done so far:

1. It must be associative because multiplication is associative under the real numbers. That means that it must apply to this set as well.
2. The identity is 1, since a*1=|a*1|=a and 1*b=|1*b|=b
3. The inverse is 1/x, where x is any number in the set.

I've been told that there is no inverse in this set, but I don't believe that is correct. Could someone help confirm whether or not there is an inverse in the set?

Comment: Are you sure that $a * 1 = a$ in all circumstances? What is $-1 * 1$?

Answer (score 4):

Look at #2 more carefully. Does $|a|=a$ for all nonzero real numbers?